# Entity Framework и связка Master-Detail

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Допустим, имеется 2 таблицы . Одна таблица ссылается на другую через внешний ключ, который не может быть NULL. `Entety2.Foreign` ссылается на `Entity1.Primary`.

Ключевое поле имеет тип `IDENTITY`.

Для того, что бы осуществить вставку я создаю сначала запись в главной таблице и выполняю сохранение.

Потом создаю запись во второй таблице и делаю `Entety2.Foreign=Entity1.Primary`.

Правильно ли так делать или есть способ проще, для работы с зависимыми таблицами?

Comment: Судя вот по [этому](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158795/best-practise-way-for-master-detail-multi-table-insert-in-entity-framework), можно просто связать элементы между собой, добавить в оба списка и сделать один SaveChanges(). Ещё интересно, правильно ли EF обрабатывает обратную операцию -- удаление обеих записей вместе.

Comment: @nzeemin, если не ошибаюсь, то нужно ручками удалять, если нет каскадного удаления...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

предположим модели выглядят как то так:

```
public class Request
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<RequestHistory> Histories {get;set;}
}

pubilc RequestHistory
{
    public int ReqiestId {get;set;}
}
```

тогда можно воспользоваться *навигационными свойствами* для вставки зависимой записи:

```
var request = //
var history = //

using(var db = new DefaultContext())
{
    db.Requests.Add(request);
    db.SaveChanges();
    request.Histories.Add(history);
    db.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

на основании [документации](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx)

должно работать так:

```
var request = //
var history = //
request.Histories.Add(history);

using(var db = new DefaultContext())
{    
    db.Requests.Add(request);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

на основании чего Entity Framework добавит записи в необходимые таблицы

Comment: Это по сути тоже самое, что я сейчас и делаю, только без навигационных свойств. А нет вариантов, что бы за одно сохранение EF все сам разрулил?

Comment: Т.е записей из обоих таблиц физически нет в бд и при сохранении контекста, EF сам проставляет внешний ключ.

Comment: @iluxa1810 если верить [этому](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) то приведенный мной способ должен работать без первого `db.SaveChanges()`, если я правильно понял то это то что Вы хотите.